# How to feed success url with pk from saved model?

Tags: python, django, url, args

I create a new model with the CompanyCreateView.
After saving it with `f.save()`, I want the browser to load the success url

```
    url(r'^comp/(?P<pk>\w+)/$', CompanyDetailView.as_view(), name="profile"),
```

Here my CreateView.

```
class CompanyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Company
    form_class = CompanyForm
    success_url = "/comp/???pk???"

    def form_valid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.submitter_id = 99 # dont know how to remove the submitter, its not set in the model
        f.save()

        return super(CreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
        return reverse("profile", kwargs={'pk': self.request.pk})
```

How can I use args arguments to return `pk`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def get_success_url(self, **kwargs):
    # obj = form.instance or self.object
    return reverse("profile", kwargs={'pk': self.object.pk})
```

You expect a primary key on the request object, which makes no sense. The instance (self.object) is where you should retrieve the primary key from.